# Getting connections stats for circuits on Spring cloud zuul

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I am running a few micro service instances that are functioning as edge routers and have the @EnableZuulProxy annotation.  I have written a number of filters and these control the flow of requests into the system.

What I would like to do is get the circuit stats from what is going on under the covers.  I see that there is a underlying netflix class DynamicServerListLoadBalancer that has some of the sts I would like to see.  Is it possible to get an instance of it and at specific time get the stats form it>

I can see it has stuff like this: (I formatted a log statement that I saw in my logs)

```
c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client authserver initialized:
    DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{
        NFLoadBalancer:
            name=authserver,current
                list of Servers=[127.0.0.1:9999],
                 Load balancer stats=
                    Zone stats: {
                        defaultzone=[
                            Zone:defaultzone;
                            Instance count:1;
                            Active connections count: 0;
                            Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;
                            Active connections per server: 0.0;]
                        },
                    Server stats:
                        [[
                            Server:127.0.0.1:9999;
                            Zone:defaultZone;
                            Total Requests:0;
                            Successive connection failure:0;
                            Total blackout seconds:0;
                            Last connection made:Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969;
                            First connection made: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969;
                            Active Connections:0;
                            total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0;
                            average resp time:0.0;  9
                            0 percentile resp time:0.0;
                            95 percentile resp time:0.0;
                            min resp time:0.0;
                            max resp time:0.0;
                            stddev resp time:0.0
                        ]]
                    }
                 ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@5b1b78aa
```

All of this would be valuable to get and act on.  Mostly the acting would be to feed usage heuristics back to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, like most of these things, I figured it out myself.

So here you go.

```
HystrixCommandKey hystrixCommandKey = HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey("what you are looking for");
HystrixCommandMetrics hystrixCommandMetrics = HystrixCommandMetrics.getInstance(hystrixCommandKey);
HystrixCommandProperties properties = hystrixCommandMetrics.getProperties();
long maxConnections = properties.executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests().get().longValue();
boolean circuitOpen = properties.circuitBreakerForceOpen().get().booleanValue();
int currentConnections = hystrixCommandMetrics.getCurrentConcurrentExecutionCount();
```

So in this example, "what you are looking for" is the hysteria command that you are looking for.

this gets you the properties of the particular hysteria thing you are looking for.

Form this you pull out the max connections, the current connections and whether the circuit was open.

So there you are.